# Is it necessary to url encode placeIDs in google maps/direction api?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

It seems like it's not necessary judging from all the placeIDs that I've seen so far. So just making sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is no longer necessary. As far as I know, **placeIDs** doesn't contain spaces, characters outside the **[ASCII set](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp)** and any reserved ASCII characters, so convertion or **[URL Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)** won't be necessary, as well with **encyrption**.

> A **place ID** is a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a
>   place. The length of the identifier may vary. Examples:
>
> - ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0
> - EisxMyBNYXJrZXQgU3RyZWV0LCBXaWxtaW5ndG9uLCBOQyAyODQwMSwgVVNB

You can also save place IDs for later use. Place IDs are exempt from the caching restrictions stated in **[Section 10.5.d](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_5)** of the Google Maps APIs Terms of Service. You can therefore store place ID values for later use. Just refresh your stored place IDs periodically, after 100 days to avoid **NOT_FOUND** status code.  To learn more about Place IDs, you can check **[Google Places API Place IDs](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#save-id)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer :)

Comment: I was wondering if you don't mind adding to your answer to say "doesn't contain characters outside the ASCII set and any reserved ASCII characters". Just that one little thing.

Comment: I believe there's one more little thing. The space, which isn't considered a reserved ASCII character but it is still an ASCII character nonetheless. "doesn't contain characters outside the ASCII set, any reserved ASCII characters, and space". seems to be good. your thoughts?

Comment: makes sense :). I've added "spaces" after the "contain" word